# How to show grouping of Test methods in Extent reports based on TEST groups

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Please refer to the sample testng.xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Main Test Suite" verbose="2">
    <test name="Sample registration tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.Practice.PracticeTest1" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
    <test name="Sample login tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.Practice.PracticeTest2" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

The file contains 2 Test Groups  named Sample registration tests and Sample login tests and under that 1 test class in each group. Now I have configured Extent reports for my project and when running the reports are coming fine. But all the test methods in the 2 classes are coming sequentially.

[Report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ve9n.png)

I want to show the test methods grouped under the Test groups. Like 
all the methods of **PracticeTest1** test class will come under **Sample registration tests** Test group and like that.

Answer (score -2):

Actually You're not grouping tests by the meanings of TestNG in your .xml, You're just naming them. To group tests add argument 'groups' under @Test annotation, like this:

```
public class Test1 {
  @Test(groups = { "functest", "checkintest" })
  public void testMethod1() {
  }

  @Test(groups = {"functest", "checkintest"} )
  public void testMethod2() {
  }

  @Test(groups = { "functest" })
  public void testMethod3() {
  }
}
```

And then in .xml configure your test run:

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="functest"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <classes>
    <class name="example1.Test1"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```

For more info about grouping Your tests visit
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Here by grouping I meant to say viewing in the extent report. Does extent report provide any filters by which all the classes under a <Test></Test> tag will come together in the report.

Comment: I didn't use the extend report, so I can't answer Your question.